# Separate double to triple whitespace and leave single whitespace untouch

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am trying to split double or more whitespace into a different row but leave the single whitespace untouch.

```
    text <- c("Hello,   how are   you doing?")
```

This is the outcome I want.

```
    Hello,
    how are
    you doing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `{}` notation for regex to select all multiple white spaces:

```
cat(gsub(" {2,}","\n",text))
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Is there any website that explains the regex argument?

Comment: https://regex101.com/, https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html

Comment: Thank you so much!